# Ajax value not received by controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have this code that got properly delivered to its controller counterpart.
but for some reason the search model data was only nulls,while the pageNumber is received properly
did i made a mistake somewhere?

```
 $("#NextResult").click(function () {
            var xData= document.getElementById("x1").value;
            var yData= document.getElementById("y1").value;

            var searchModel = {
                xval: xData,
                yval: yData,
            };
            var pageNumber = @Model.Page +1;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Work/FilterData",
                type: "GET",
                data: { 'searchModel': searchModel, 'pageNumber': pageNumber },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError);
                }

            }).success(function (response) {
                $('#datas').html(response)
            })
        });
```

the Controller is as such

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FilterData(WorkSearchModel searchModel,int? pageNumber)

{
```

EDIT:

as suggested i tried doing doing both on a different project (this makes the function uncallable so i presume there's an error somewhere)

```
$("#NextResult").click(function () {
            var xData= document.getElementById("x1").value;
            var yData= document.getElementById("y1").value;
     var searchModel = {
        xval: xData,
                yval: yData,
                       pageNumber = @Model.Page +1
    };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Work/FilterData",
            type: "GET",
            data: searchModel,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }

        }).success(function (response) {
            $('#datas').html(response)
        })
    });
```

i also have tried to do this but nothing works (this gives null values for both searchmodel and pagenumber now)

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/Work/FilterData",
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringify(searchModel, pageNumber),
        contentType: "application/json;",
```

Comment: Change it to `var data = { xval: xData, yval: yData, pageNumber: @Model.Page +1 };` and then `data: data,` (i.e. all values in one object). Alternatively you must stringify the data and set the`contentType` to `'application/json'`

Comment: if i do so would i still need to change the action result in the controller? and how do i make sure that only xval and yval are included as the WorkSearchModel?

Comment: No you do not need to change the controller (and I assume `WorkSearchModel` contains those 2 properties) - try it!

Comment: var data = {
            xval: xData,
            yval: yData,
            pageNumber:@Model.Page +1
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Work/FilterData",
            type: "GET",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json;",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        }).success(function (response) {

            $('#datas').html(response)
        })
i tried doing this but it's giving me empty response

Comment: Read the first comment again - one or the other!

Comment: i tried to do both but it didnt work out. i've posted the source code that i edited for reference

Comment: Then you have other problems with code you have not shown us.

Comment: yeah i gave up trying to solve it.... I ended up just adding the pageNumber inside the WorkSearchModel module and it worked

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4pXTD3) for a working example (I'll be deleting it in a day or so)

Comment: Note with the option using `JSON.stringify()` and `contentType: "application/json;",` you also need to make it a post.

Comment: thx mate i'll try it when i have the time :D

Answer (score 0):

I would change the call from a GET to POST

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to send the parameters one by one in the query string like this

```
$("#NextResult").click(function () {
    var xData= document.getElementById("x1").value;
    var yData= document.getElementById("y1").value;

    var pageNumber = @Model.Page +1;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Work/FilterData?xval=xData&yval=yData&pageNumber=pageNumber",
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }

    }).success(function (response) {
        $('#datas').html(response)
    })
});
```

And the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FilterData(int xval, int yval, int? pageNumber)
```